# rosinstall error

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

why when i try to run rosinstall i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.5.30', 'rosinstall')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 467, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1200, in run_script
    execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosinstall-0.5.30-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 28, in <module>
    import rosinstall.helpers
ImportError: No module named rosinstall.helpers
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28822/rosinstall-error/) by [vahid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1777/vahid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-02-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

please reinstall rosinstall, its libraries seem to be missing from your pythonpath.

see http://ros.org/wiki/rosinstall

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1